# Android application could not run properly on screen sizes less than 4 inch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen, android-screen-support

I'm developing a small application but I'm having problem while deploying the application on screen sizes smaller than 4 inches. I have tried it on a 3.2 inch screen, the whole layout is mixed up with each other. I have searched for this problem a lot of time and tried some of the methods like making folders with `layout-small`, `layout-normal` and `layout-large`. This does not give me the proper layout.

And one more thing I could not decide which images to put in ldpi or mdpi or hdpi. Right now for better image resolution I'm putting all the images in hdpi folder. Is this way a correct way to develop an android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen size and screen density are separate issues

For small screen use a separate layout file res/layout-small/main.xml
Your drawable assets could be in appropriate folder depending on the density of the device.

e.g sony xperia mini is a xhdpi device while more of the other devices with 3.2 screen might be ldpi or mdpi devices.